# Retrieve data from php to jquery and insert it into DataTable

Tags: php, html, mysql, datatable, bootstrap-4

I want to refresh content of table from database , so when user pressed refresh button I will retrieve data from database via php , and send this data to jquery which will working on insert retrieved data into table ,I can retrieve data successfully but can not insert it in to datatable 
this is php code which retrieve data from database;

```html
    elseif ($id=='refresh_logs'){

   $shortname=$_GET['shortname'];
      $data_array = array();
    $bul="select radacct.UserName,radacct.AcctStartTime,radacct.AcctStopTime,radacct.AcctOutputOctets,radacct.AcctInputOctets,AcctSessionTime,FramedIPAddress,os.mac,nas.shortname,os_platform,acctupdatetime ,RadAcctId from radacct Left join os on os.username=radacct.UserName and os.AcctSessionid=radacct.AcctSessionId left join nas on radacct.NASIPAddress = nas.nasname where nas.shortname='$shortname' limit 1";
 //echo($bul);
 $result2 = $con2->query($bul);
  while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $upload=round($row['AcctOutputOctets']/1024/1024,2);
   
    $download=round($row['AcctInputOctets']/1024/1024,2);
   if ($row['AcctSessionTime']<60) {
      $sure=$row['AcctSessionTime']." Sec";
    }
   else {
     $gun=floor($row['AcctSessionTime']/86400);
     $saat=floor(($row['AcctSessionTime'] - $gun*86400)/3600);
     $dakika=floor(($row['AcctSessionTime'] - $gun*86400 - $saat*3600)/60);
     $sure="";
     if ($dakika>0){
       $sure=$dakika." Min";
      }
     if ($saat>0){
       $sure=$saat." Hour ".$sure;
     }
     if ($gun>0){
      $sure=$gun." Day ".$sure;
      }
    }
   $row['upload']=$upload;
   $row['download']=$download;
   $row['sure']=$sure;
    array_push($data_array,$row);
    
    
    
    }

   $data_array=json_encode($data_array); 
 echo $format = '{
"data":['.$data_array.']}';
 
}
```

this is the jquery code to insert retrieved data into table

```
$('.refresh').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var string ='';
    var nas_shortname=$('#nas_shortname').val();

    var jsonData = $.ajax({ async: false,
      url: "Save.php?id=refresh_logs&shortname="+nas_shortname,

      dataType: "json"

      }).responseText;
        //}

var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
$('#resultt').html('<img src="dist/img/ajax_loader_red_128.gif"/>');
$('#my_logs tbody ').remove();







$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
var table = $('#my_logs').DataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": obj,
"sScrollY": "300px",
"scrollX":true,
"paging": false,
"bFilter": false,
"bInfo": false,
"searching": false,
"bSort" : false,
"fixedColumns":   true
});


$('#resultt').html('OK');
}); 



});
```

I have this error in console

> DataTables warning: table id=my_logs - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
>       at J (VM2914 jquery.dataTables.min.js:74)

this is json data which I send from server side to jquery

```
[{"UserName":"root2","AcctStartTime":"2018-10-18 15:52:52","AcctStopTime":null,"AcctOutputOctets":"0","AcctInputOctets":"0","AcctSessionTime":"0","FramedIPAddress":"192.168.33.3","CallingStationId":"192.168.33.3","shortname":"radius2_nas1","os_platform":null,"acctupdatetime":"2018-10-18 15:52:52","RadAcctId":"1","upload":0,"download":0,"sure":"0 Sec"},{"UserName":"root","AcctStartTime":"2018-10-18 16:07:00","AcctStopTime":null,"AcctOutputOctets":"0","AcctInputOctets":"0","AcctSessionTime":"0","FramedIPAddress":"192.168.33.3","CallingStationId":"192.168.33.3","shortname":"radius2_nas1","os_platform":null,"acctupdatetime":"2018-10-18 16:07:00","RadAcctId":"2","upload":0,"download":0,"sure":"0 Sec"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

From PHP side your `$data_array` should be like below:

```
Array
(
[draw] => 1
[recordsTotal] => 4827
[recordsFiltered] => 4827
[data] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [UserName] => root2
                [AcctStartTime] => 2018-10-18 15:52:52 
                [AcctStopTime] => 
                [AcctOutputOctets] => 0
                [AcctInputOctets] => 0
                [AcctSessionTime] => 0
                [FramedIPAddress] => 192.168.33.3
                [CallingStationId] => 192.168.33.3
                [shortname] => radius2_nas1
                [os_platform] => 
                [acctupdatetime] => 2018-10-18 15:52:52
                [RadAcctId] => 1
                [upload] => 0
                [download] => 0
                [sure] => 0 Sec
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [UserName] => root3
                [AcctStartTime] => 2018-10-18 15:52:52 
                [AcctStopTime] => 
                [AcctOutputOctets] => 0
                [AcctInputOctets] => 0
                [AcctSessionTime] => 0
                [FramedIPAddress] => 192.168.33.3
                [CallingStationId] => 192.168.33.3
                [shortname] => radius2_nas1
                [os_platform] => 
                [acctupdatetime] => 2018-10-18 15:52:52
                [RadAcctId] => 1
                [upload] => 0
                [download] => 0
                [sure] => 0 Sec
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [UserName] => root4
                [AcctStartTime] => 2018-10-18 15:52:52 
                [AcctStopTime] => 
                [AcctOutputOctets] => 0
                [AcctInputOctets] => 0
                [AcctSessionTime] => 0
                [FramedIPAddress] => 192.168.33.3
                [CallingStationId] => 192.168.33.3
                [shortname] => radius2_nas1
                [os_platform] => 
                [acctupdatetime] => 2018-10-18 15:52:52
                [RadAcctId] => 1
                [upload] => 0
                [download] => 0
                [sure] => 0 Sec
            )
        ...

     )
)
```

After `json_encode()` Your response data have to be as below :

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":4827,"recordsFiltered":4827,"data":[{"UserName":"root2","AcctStartTime":"2018-10-18 15:52:52","AcctStopTime":null,"AcctOutputOctets":"0","AcctInputOctets":"0","AcctSessionTime":"0","FramedIPAddress":"192.168.33.3","CallingStationId":"192.168.33.3","shortname":"radius2_nas1","os_platform":null,"acctupdatetime":"2018-10-18 15:52:52","RadAcctId":"1","upload":0,"download":0,"sure":"0 Sec"},{"UserName":"root","AcctStartTime":"2018-10-18 16:07:00","AcctStopTime":null,"AcctOutputOctets":"0","AcctInputOctets":"0","AcctSessionTime":"0","FramedIPAddress":"192.168.33.3","CallingStationId":"192.168.33.3","shortname":"radius2_nas1","os_platform":null,"acctupdatetime":"2018-10-18 16:07:00","RadAcctId":"2","upload":0,"download":0,"sure":"0 Sec"}]}
```

You can also check **json is valid or not on https://jsonlint.com/**

In case if you don't get success in retrieving serverside datatable as per your need then **you can follow  [Datatable's Serverside example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)**